# Permission denied when trying to give Jenkins ssh access to private github repo

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh

I have a private repository (organization repo) in github.

I generated rsa keys, added the public one to the github repo (with read access only).

I created credentials on Jenkins. I added the private key to it:

[image]

When configuring the job, it gives me the following error:

> Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h
>   git@github.com:XXX-Team/XXx-datalake-dataflow.git HEAD" returned
>   status code 128: stdout: stderr: Permission denied (publickey). fatal:
>   Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists

[image]

Could someone explain what I did wrong and how to fix it ?

Comment: Have you verified you can ssh to github with the private key?  You should see a message saying you've successfully authenticated.

Comment: @StephenNewell Yes, I can clone with this SSH key.

Comment: I checked my jobs, and I'm using the ID field for credentials, and it looks like you're using the username.  For what it's worth I'm using pipelines, but I assume it'd be the same for other job types.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that ? I'm using freestyle project and in the credentials list, there is only "none" and the one I selected. @StephenNewell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot to put the passphrase of the private key when creating the credentials on Jenkins...

Thanks @VonC for his answer that made me think about it.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Double check (again) that `ssh -Tv -i /path/to/private_key git@github.com` does work.

Then double-check you have copied the full private key, from `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` up until `-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`